# How To Import OpenCV Lib Into Python?

Tags: python, opencv

i searched here and couldn't find almost anything even near to the answer.
i have downloaded the .tar package of OpenCV 2.4.2 and extracted it, then i made a directory outside the original folder of openCv then called `cmake`, it took a while, then i called `make` & then `sudo make install` .
it all happened without any errors, then i reinstalled my python and called it.
then tried `import cv` and i'm still getting :

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: libavcodec.so.53: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Chakra Claire.

and another thing, is it true that openCV wont be supported for python 3?

Answer (score 0):

It seems OpenCV is looking for `libavcodec.so.53` and can't find it!

libavcodec might not ne installed on your system, or it's not located in the default system paths.

If you have it, make sure this path is set on the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (linux).

Comment: the problem is i don't know how to do that?
can u explain more precisely?

Comment: Execute `sudo find / -iname libavcodec.so.53` to locate the file. If the file exists and is located at /usr/local/lib, it's important that you add this path to the environment variable I mentioned: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`. If you don't find the file, then you need to install the package, and if you are on Ubuntu you should do: `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53 libavcodec53`. Read [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095) for details.